# How to create RAW-Email-Message on AWS-SES in Swift 5

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to create a RAW-Email inside my iOS-App. 
Looking to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html#send-email-mime-encoding), 
I need to encode my message to MIME-Standard, but I'm not so familiar with this topic. In the documentation there is also example-code for python and java.

How can I achieve this in SWIFT?

```
func sendRawMail(){
    let sender = "sender@mail.com"
    let recipient = "recipient@mail.com"

    let rawMessage = AWSSESRawMessage()
   // rawMessage?.data = "I guess HERE I have to put the MIME-   Data?!"
    let rawRequest = AWSSESSendRawEmailRequest()
    rawRequest?.destinations = [recipient]
    rawRequest?.source = sender

    rawRequest?.rawMessage = rawMessage

    AWSSES.default().sendRawEmail(rawRequest!) { (response, error) in
        if let response = response{
            print(response)
        }
        if let error = error{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Sending an empty mail with my code works so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reading, I finally get it working. 
You need to write a big string, based on MIME-Standards.
This big string you have to encode to BASE64.
Attachments needed also to transform from data to an BASE64-String.

I will post my code, which can send Mails with an .png image. I will test other fileTypes as well, but it have to be the same principle.

First I created a enum for my fileTypes.

```
enum DataTypes{
case png
case jpg
case pdf
}
```

Now I created a function to get the string-value for the specific DataType

```
func getMIMEDataType(dataType:DataTypes) -> String{
    var MIMEData = String()
    switch dataType {
    case .png:
        MIMEData = "image/png"
    case .jpg:
        MIMEData = "image/jpg"
    case .pdf:
        MIMEData = "application/pdf"
    }
    return MIMEData
}
```

Finally the function to send the raw-mail. There are already variables in the message-string so you can use this function flexible.

```
func sendRawMail(sender:String,reciepients:[String],subject:String,message:String,attachment:Data?,dataType:DataTypes?,attachmentName:String?,completion: @escaping (_ messageCode:String?,_ error:Error?) -> ()){

    let attachmentString = attachment!.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

    let MIMEDataType = getMIMEDataType(dataType: dataType!)

    let message:String = """
    Subject: \(subject)
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
            boundary="XXXXboundary text"

    This is a multipart message in MIME format.

    --XXXXboundary text
    Content-Type: text/plain

    \(message)

    --XXXXboundary text
    Content-Type: \(MIMEDataType);
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="\(attachmentName!).\(MIMEDataType.components(separatedBy: "/")[1])"

    \(attachmentString)

    --XXXXboundary text--
    """

    let data = message.data(using: .utf8)
    let rawMessage = AWSSESRawMessage()
    rawMessage?.data = data
    let rawRequest = AWSSESSendRawEmailRequest()
    rawRequest?.destinations = reciepients
    rawRequest?.source = sender

    rawRequest?.rawMessage = rawMessage

    AWSSES.default().sendRawEmail(rawRequest!) { (response, error) in
        if let response = response{
            completion(response.messageId,nil)
        }
        if let error = error{
            completion(nil,error)
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this and can handle the result in the completionHandler.

```
sendRawMail(sender: "sender.mail@mail.com", reciepients: ["recipient.mail@mail.com"], subject: "This is a test", message: "TestMessage", attachment: attachment.data, dataType: .png, attachmentName: "testpicture") { (messageID, error) in
                    if let messageID = messageID{
                        print(messageID)
                    }
                    if let error = error{
                        print(error)
                    }
```

I hope it will help somebody in future :)

Comment: I have used the code you have written above but using this code I am not able to send the email to the gmail id's. Even though I am getting the message id's but the email is not received by the recipient. Is there any problem with the header part, as we are not sending any header in the message. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: If you are receiving the message id there should be no problem from AWS. As you mentioned, it only occurs at gmail, I would suggest to look at their documents, if gmail need some specific headers. 
Until today my code works fine in my application, but I haven't registered any gmail accounts..

Comment: Is there any way that we could send the images as attachments in the email using amazon ses sendEmail function rather then using sendRawEmail?

Comment: Do I need to send any header information so that it can be received by the gmail recipients?

Comment: Maybe you can analyze an gmail-email, when you are sending it to yourself. If they need some kind of specific header you can write a function in your swift-code, which detects gmail-mails and create the required header.

Comment: I have figured it out, the problem in your code is you are using the message of string type as it is for creating the large string, this is creating the problem. I then converted this string to the base 64 string and then used it in creating the large string. This solved my problem and now I am able to receive emails on gmail and yahoo mail clients as well. But your code has given me the starting idea and thanks a lot for your code.